# java read text file column headers in random order

Tags: java

I recieve a file each day that:

- is stab delimited
- has 5 or more columns
- has 3 common columns - lastName, firstName, address

Problem: the column order of the file changes regularly

Goal: print column data for lastName, firstName, address regardless of column order

I have been using the following code and manually changing the datavalues to match the columns.

```
testfile1.txt
1st day file format
ID  lastName    address         phone           firstName
45   Gates      111 some lane   777-888-9999    Bill

2nd day file format
address         ID  phone           firstName   lastName
111 some lane   81  444-555-1111    John        Doe
```

-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String dataFileName = "C:/testfiles/testfile1.txt";
        String line;
        int lineNumber = 0;

        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFileName));
        bReader.readLine();

        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;
            String datavalue[] = line.split("\t");
            String lastName = datavalue[1];
            String firstName = datavalue[5];
            String address = datavalue[3];

            System.out.println(lastName + "'" + firstName + "," + address);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a first approach. I would try it somehow like this:

```
int colLastName, colFirstName, colAddress;
line = bReader.readLine();
String columnOrder []= line.split("\t");
for (int i=0; i< columnOrder.length; i++){
if (columnOrder[i].equals("lastName")){
  colLastName = i;
}
else if (columnOrder[i].equals("firstName"){
  colFirstName = i;
}
else if (columnOrder[i].equals("address"){
  colAddress = i;
}
}


    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lineNumber++;
        String datavalue[] = line.split("\t");
        String lastName = datavalue[colLastName];
        String firstName = datavalue[colFirstName];
        String address = datavalue[colAddress];

        System.out.println(lastName + "'" + firstName + "," + address);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like below -

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String dataFileName = "C:/testfiles/testfile1.txt";
        String line;
        boolean isFirstColumn = true;

        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFileName));
        int[] order_Fname_Lname_Address = new int[3];

        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {

            String datavalue[] = line.split("\t");

            if(isFirstColumn) {
                for (int i = 0; i < datavalue.length; i++) {
                    switch (datavalue[i]) {
                    case "firstName":
                        order_Fname_Lname_Address[0] = i;
                    break;
                    case "lastName":
                        order_Fname_Lname_Address[1] = i;
                    break;
                    case "address":
                        order_Fname_Lname_Address[2] = i;
                    break;
                    }
                }
                isFirstColumn = false;
                continue;
            }

            String firstName = datavalue[order_Fname_Lname_Address[0]];
            String lastName = datavalue[order_Fname_Lname_Address[1]];
            String address = datavalue[order_Fname_Lname_Address[2]];

            System.out.println(lastName + " " + firstName + "," + address);
        }
        bReader.close();
    }
}
```